# Can't connect to remote desktop via Cisco VPN using wireless connection, works with wired

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, remote-desktop, vpn, cisco-vpn-client

I have a laptop using Windows 7 64bit connected over wireless connection to a router  and then onto the Internet. That laptop was connecting to a Windows 2000 Server over remote desktop through Cisco ASA device using Cisco VPN client version 5.

The problem is that if I connect to the security appliance using the VPN client over wireless, I can't connect to the Remote Desktop server (and can't ping any computers on the other side of the tunnel but should be able to), but everything used to work fine few weeks ago. If I connect over wired connection, everything works fine. I also have another laptop which connects the same way and everything works fine on it.

In the VPN client logs, I can see that it establishes tunnel and I can see that dead peer detection is working fine. Comparing the logs VPN between the computer on which connection works fine and the one on which it doesn't, I can't see any major differences at all.

To make things worse, I'm not the primary user of those two computers, so I don't know if any settings were changed on them. I'm told that nothing was changed on them except anything windows update may have done.  Also nothing was changed on the ASA.

On the problematic laptoptop, following commands did restore connectivity for a while:

```
netsh advfirewall reset
netsh branchcache reset
netsh int ip reset
netsh int ipv6 reset
netsh winsock reset
```

Unfortunately, I entered all commands at once, so I don't know which one did the trick and it worked only once.

I've also tired disabling firewall on the affected computer, but it didn't help.

So any ideas what could go wrong?